# Typescript function overload with rest parameters

Tags: typescript, types, overloading

I have a code like this, with a couple of overloaded functions with rest parameters:

```js
    type IAuthSelectors =
      | 'selector1'
      | 'selector2'
      | 'selector3'
      | 'selector4'
      | 'selector5'
      | 'selector6';

    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector1'): string[];
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector2', param1: string): boolean;
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector3'): boolean;
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector4'): string;
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector5'): MyInterface;
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector6'): string;
    function getAuthState(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): unknown
    function getAuthState(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): unknown {
      // return logic
    }

    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector1'): string[];
    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector2', param1: string): boolean;
    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector3'): boolean;
    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector4'): string;
    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector5'): MyInterface;
    function useAuthSelector(selector: 'selector6'): string;
    function useAuthSelector(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): unknown {
      const authState = getAuthState(selector, ...selectorArguments); // ERROR A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

      // ...
    }
```

But I cannot make one to call the other. The error:
`ERROR A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)`
is pretty clear. But if I try to cast it to a tuple it breaks. I have also tried checking the number of rest parameters to call it with parameters or not, but it doesn't work.

Right now, this has only one "selector" with rest parameters, but there could be more in the future. I added the overload functions to have proper types in the components calling them.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

EDIT: If I add the spread overload, it doesn't fail, but I can do something like this:

```js
    type IAuthSelectors =
      | 'selector1'
      | 'selector2';

    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector1'): string[];
    function getAuthState(selector: 'selector2', param1: string): boolean;
    function getAuthState(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): unknown
    function getAuthState(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): unknown {
      // return logic
    }

getAuthState('selector1', 'param1', 'param2'); // NO ERROR
```

Any way to keep the inference of parameters? If I add the spread overload it no longer infers the other prototypes.

Comment: The implementation signature isn't accessible, only the overloads.

Comment: I saw that. It does not throw error anymore, but it does not behave as I expected :S How can I make it know the desired arguments? I have edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the possible arguments for the two functions are identical.

It's not unusual inside an overload implementation for types to be a bit ... loose. :-) You might just suppress the error via `ts-expect-error` (and not expose the rest arguments versions of the calls), since you know the arguments are correct. I'm not a fan of doing that most of the time, but overloads tend to go this way (but keep reading).

```typescript
function useAuthSelector(selector: IAuthSelectors, ...selectorArguments: unknown[]): any {
    // @ts-expect-error
    const authState = getAuthState(selector, ...selectorArguments);
    //    ^? const authState: never

    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSA7YEBOAzAhgY2gXigG8APALigGdhUBLRAcwG4oBfRgKFEingEEBXYAAsAyhAA2EbMAD2qClDzsoKqAB8oAcgoSps1AEZNy1Ru27pcgEzHV6rTsmXUAZlumHF-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) *(side note: In there, I fixed the return type of the overload implementation functions, which should be `any` or a union of all the possible return types from the overload signatures, not `unknown`)*

**But**, aside from the "ewww" factor of using `ts-expect-error`, there's also the devex issue that `authCheck`'s type would be `never`. :-|

Alternatively, you could use a mapped type for the parameters and return type instead of overloads (but keep reading):

```typescript
type IAuthSelectors =
    | "selector1"
    | "selector2"
    | "selector3"
    | "selector4"
    | "selector5"
    | "selector6";

type SelectorCall<Selector extends IAuthSelectors> =
    Selector extends "selector1"
    ? {
          params: [];
          returnType: string[];
      }
    : Selector extends "selector2"
    ? {
          params: [param1: string];
          returnType: boolean;
      }
    : Selector extends "selector3"
    ? {
          params: [];
          returnType: boolean;
      }
    : Selector extends "selector4"
    ? {
          params: [];
          returnType: string;
      }
    : Selector extends "selector5"
    ? {
          params: [];
          returnType: MyInterface;
      }
    : Selector extends "selector6"
    ? {
          params: [];
          returnType: string;
      }
    : never;

function getAuthState<Selector extends IAuthSelectors, CallType extends SelectorCall<Selector>>(
    selector: Selector,
    ...params: CallType["params"]
): CallType["returnType"] {
    return null as any as CallType["returnType"];
}

function useAuthSelector<Selector extends IAuthSelectors, CallType extends SelectorCall<Selector>>(
    selector: Selector,
    ...params: CallType["params"]
): CallType["returnType"] {
    const authState = getAuthState(selector, ...params);

    return authState;
}

const x = useAuthSelector("selector1");
//    ^? const x: string[]
const y = useAuthSelector("selector2", "param value");
//    ^? const y: boolean
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSA7YEBOAzAhgY2gXigG8oAPALigGdhUBLRAcygF8BuAKFEingEEBXYAAsAyhAA2EbMAD2qSlDzsoKqAB8oAIkoSps1AEZNy1Ru27pcgEzHV6rTsmXUAZlumHF-QBZ3Ks456cgCsfvbmTvoAbJocnODQYpFyAMKY4uIAPElBqFAQJCiIACYKfIKiXnKUAHyKJio5zvmFECUKEblGDVAA-EQ9dipgmKiYALaUFADaALocQ0OoEMD8qIgAKgkU1HSMcwtDzD0UTfotRaWeyag2Pf2Eg0MjY5MzLxMGOzT0DPNPdmWq3WW0gFAARjIZJJMIhDnZjnZTlU8gVLh1As43PcBos7B83lADgDVEC1pttlBIdCILD4apEapkTcLm0rp1nL4cY88aoCVMif9eSoySDKbtfvSVIyVMzcqz2tdcqFuSThqMJgLicKoKKKWDYAhkGgsLgpSwTlAznIFezMdEwg81VB+TMhcK9aCIN89gxzTKoBREBAAG5oOLofiIaS0GSIKAMFYCYQiYCYFDZFG2srJyo3SgAGigaQyXuzVpRJay1tQNRqAAoeva5HLnAWegA6Luu4vpcRe6aafmaWbsACUFCrA80noSI9xpJW5KgiH4GSgmAUsJAG4UU4Sg9nkBHHGO7Ej0eAsfj-B0uZrmZZaLZOYqNcLvdLCXLNarj9ydaNnYzaoK2+jtnYXYdj2+6QIOw6jhOn79geM5LmKx6zAuKjYHG1Abm+aYoIoCZJoR6YQPWIFFlB-JjnEgLofGmDkSgp7sOwuGIPhJAkbeED3ii9YcvoRj0ewAD0El2AAer0nF4cAUA7gQ-GCTcwkgTYRZDhq4xQCG6T8BAmjiVJsnyUAA)

You still get argument suggestions and auto-complete, etc. Thanks to *named tuple elements*, you even get the name `param1` showing when you do `useAuthSelector("selector2", _`:

[image: IDE showing parameter name for param1 when "selector2" is used for the selector parameter]

[caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972297/typescript-function-overload-with-rest-parameters/73973295?noredirect=1#comment130615079_73973295) that mapped conditionals like that are fairly slow (at compile time) and this one could easily be replaced with a lookup. Quite true! **And** doing so means we don't have to repeat the selector names, because we can derive `IAUthSelectors` from that lookup type, like this:

```typescript
type SelectorCall = {
    selector1: {
        params: [];
        returnType: string[];
    };
    selector2: {
        params: [param1: string];
        returnType: boolean;
    };
    selector3: {
        params: [];
        returnType: boolean;
    };
    selector4: {
        params: [];
        returnType: string;
    };
    selector5: {
        params: [];
        returnType: MyInterface;
    };
    selector6: {
        params: [];
        returnType: string;
    };
};

type IAuthSelectors = keyof SelectorCall;
```

Then the functions are:

```typescript
function getAuthState<Selector extends IAuthSelectors, CallType extends SelectorCall[Selector]>(
    selector: Selector,
    ...params: CallType["params"]
): CallType["returnType"] {
    return null as any as CallType["returnType"];
}

function useAuthSelector<Selector extends IAuthSelectors, CallType extends SelectorCall[Selector]>(
    selector: Selector,
    ...params: CallType["params"]
): CallType["returnType"] {
    const authState = getAuthState(selector, ...params);

    return authState;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSA7YEBOAzAhgY2gXigG8oAPALigGdhUBLRAcygF8BuAKHdEigGUIANhGzAA9qgDCmAQKgFC7KEqqDhY1AEYKC5bqhhMqTAFtKFANoBdDnuWoIwAK6pEAFXAQK1Ooys3lbIrKlKoi4gBM2kG2BkamFrEmWlQ09AzW0Xr2Ti7ukBQARqKiQpiI-kqBuiFCYagAzFG2SonxUH6ZutnObh6FxaXlmVXBoeoALE3NrWbtGc1Q3bl9KT4MFSwbNWriAKxTMYYmsx0LS735sAjIaFi4GyNK23UAbAd6Mxbzzed5nqtpB4cQJcDxQeAAQUcwAAFvxaupKHIoABrCAgUToPhjcRSGQcdjoRyIES0USIKAMBxQ2G8YCYFAAHnhO1QUAgJBQiAAJkjIdC4TjUJQADRQPECP7szkQHlIll1CXmBXqSwAPgAFJlnuoKCrxCLMgA6E2fcXSSUecwAIhm1ss7AAlBQJX8bb8PPaiJlzlBEI4ZFBMEiyiAg0jXVbrR7IPbgZwiSTgGSKY4QjTBQjxMyhdKubzwRn9cKxZGeBz8-KhUri+qtdUhXqhYbdCajWayxAbXaHc7zTI3dGHD0-l6dMpsOTqEGBXSGfhKdTZ-SUBqdQaoG2Zo6CV1hy4Z7SVxB4+xJ4hpyRkWmIEWhRrrevNNad+wAPRv3QAPQA-Gep8AUBhgQN53lmqAPk+4TWmKtpHMYUAAG7SI4EAvhwH7fn+QA)

Usage is the same, as is the IDE experience (with parameter names and such).

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!!! I have not experimented much with conditional types, I think it's time to give them a try.

Comment: You might want to consider changing that long chain of conditionals to a lookup table for performance. Conditionals are still pretty slow :P

Comment: @caTS - Thanks. You know, I did think about a lookup when I was doing it, and then...seem to have kinda forgotten. :) Also lets us avoid repeating the selector strings; `type IAuthSelectors = keyof SelectorCall;` :D